# ASP.NET Core Middleware executes before authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

As part of the login flow, I need to check that a user has access to the application I'm writing. I do this by querying a legacy db with the user id. Afterwards, I want to add the legacy id to the request so I don't have to look it up each time. So I build a policy that retrieves the legacy id of the logged in user and adds it to the request. Then I wrote a `LoggingMiddleware` to add that legacy id as a log property.

Both work nicely, but are executed in the wrong order. First the middleware is executed and then the authentication policy. So I'm constantly logging 'Anonymous' instead of the id I want to log. My `Startup` class has the correct order (I think), so I don't understand why it won't work correctly.

Startup.cs:

```
    public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      var authenticationSettings = Configuration.GetSection(ConfigurationConstants.JwtSectionName).Get<AuthenticationSettings>();
      services
        .AddAuthorization(options =>
          options.AddPolicy(SecurityConstants.PolicyName,
            new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
              .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
              .Build()))
        .AddScoped<ISecurityQueries, SecurityQueries>()
        .AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, VerifyIdPolicy>()
        .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
          options.Authority = authenticationSettings.Authority;
          options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
          {
            ValidateAudience = false,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuers = authenticationSettings.Issuers.Split(';')
          };
        });

      services
        .ConfigureMvc<ContractDomainException>(Configuration)
        .ConfigureRefitClient<IAppConfigApi>(Configuration, DataContextTypes.AppConfig)
        .ConfigureServices()
        .ConfigureSwagger("Contract HTTP API")
        .ConfigureValidation(new Dictionary<string, string> {{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, DataContextTypes.Contract}});
    }

    public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
      app
        .UseAuthentication()
        .UseCors()
        .UseMiddleware<LoggingMiddlewareTest>()
        .UseResponseCompression()
        .UseMvc();
    }
```

Controller.cs:

```
  [ApiController]
  [ApiVersion("1.0")]
  [Authorize(Policy = SecurityConstants.PolicyName)]
  public class ContractController : ControllerBase
```

Comment: The authz handler runs as part of `UseMvc` (just to explain the why). If you _always_ need to get the legacy ID, you can plug into the authentication system instead. Alternatively, a resource-filter could do the logging - these run after authz and before actions.

Comment: Just for completeness, note that the picture is a little bit different in 3.0.

Comment: I thought that using a policy (via `AuthorizationHandler<>`) was plugging it into the authentication system.

Comment: That’s the _authorisation_ system. It’s an authorisation policy, not an authentication policy. The concepts blur a little, but it’s a lot better in 3.0 with endpoint routing at least.

Comment: Aaah, I thought it was one and the same system. Like step 1. authenticate and then step 2. authorize, then continue with the next piece of middleware. If you put this in an answer, I'll give you credit for solving my problem. :)

Comment: Don’t worry about credit. Come back when you’ve solved it with your own answer - that’ll be more useful than my "hints".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was actually fairly simple. I use a piece of middleware that I register before the `LoggingMiddlewareTest`.

```
    public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
      app
        .UseAuthentication()
        .UseCors()
        .UseEndpointRouting() // new
        .UseMiddleware<FetchTechnicalUserMiddleware>() // new
        .UseMiddleware<LoggingMiddlewareTest>()
        .UseResponseCompression()
        .UseMvc();
    }
```

In this scenario, I don't need an `AuthorizationHandler<>`. I just need to make sure the `FetchTechnicalUserMiddleware` is executed before the `LoggingMiddlewareTest`. This is done by placing the fetch before the logging as they are executed in order.

The other thing that I needed to do was add the `UseEndpointRouting` setup. This allows me to access the endpoint metadata in my middleware. I add a specific `AuthorizeAttribute` to endpoints on which I need to fetch the technical user id. This allows me to do the following in my middleware:

```
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var authorization = context.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>()?.Endpoint?.Metadata.GetMetadata<AuthorizeAttribute>();
        if (authorization is PersonAuthorizeAttribute)
        {
          // fetch technical user id
        }
    }
```

Without the `UseEndpointRouting`, the `authorization` variable would always be `null`. The reason I do this is to not hit the db unnecessarily and improve performance on calls that don't need this data.

A big thanks to [Kirk Larkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2630078/kirk-larkin) for pointing me in the right direction.